# Explain underlying reasoning in this statement: "all objective-C objects must be referenced using pointers because they live on heap, not stack"

Tags: objective-c

I don't really understand why objective-c objects always are referenced with pointers .

Consider this code:

```
 // Create an array of Employee objects
 NSMutableArray *employees = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 // Create an instance of Employee
 Employee *person = [[Employee alloc] init];
 // Put the employee in the employees array
 [employees addObject:person];
 }
```

Why not something like this?

```
// Create an array of Employee objects
     NSMutableArray employees = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 // Create an instance of Employee
 Employee person = [[Employee alloc] init];
 // Put the employee in the employees array
 [employees addObject:person];
 }
```

Comment: I suppose it could have been done but, for example, consider the implications of `return employees;` as the next line in your two examples.

Comment: In the early days of Objective-C, it _was_ done.  That's why the error message for leaving out the `*` is what it is.  It's telling you that something which used to be permitted no longer is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack allocation is done by the compiler and a runtime environment. That means that there are many conventions and rules. Think about exceptions while constructing an object. Difficult to deal with them (and the same on deconstruction). The error mechanism of Cocoa while construction is very easy to understand and to implement. The construction mechanism itself is very easy to understand, to implement and highly flexible, because it is a part of the code, not of the runtime environment. If object creation happens "behind the scenes" it becomes more complex.

What is the disadvantage of "explicit" heap construction? Look to you code. You simply save an `*`, not more. No extra rules, no exceptions, no partial stack unrolling, … And with ARC the point in time to automatically delete the object is no deal anymore.

*All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection* (David Wheeler)

Answer (score 2):

Because it is Objective-C, and not C++.

As a result, all the code for addObject is in NSArray. Completely. Once. In C++, you need to write a move constructor unless you want the copy to be inefficient, templated code gets copied all over the place, and so on.